# matrix representations of linear tranformatitons

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image: linear transformation]

I am having trouble with this problem. I have to find the matrix representation of a linear transformation. The example in my book got me this question below.Can someone explain this question?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}[x]_2$? Maybe the polynomials of degree $\leq 2$...

Comment: thats why I asked to you . ı didn't understand anything :( but I thought R[x]2 the polynomials of degree <=2 so, it represents this vector (1,x,x^2)

Answer (score 1):

For the matrix of linear transformation you need to calculate the images of the basis vectors. In this case they are $1, x, x^2$, so $D(1) = 0, D(x) = 1$ and $D(x^2) = 2x$. Next you place their coordinates in the columns of the matrix like this :

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

And you are done. The first column is for image of the first basis vector - $1$, the second column is for the second - $x$ and the third column - for the image of $x^2$.

Comment: Im not the author of this topic, but I wonder how would this matrix looked like in $(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,0)$ basis?

Comment: Well find the matrix $K$, which transforms the coordinates of a vector in your basis to the coordinates of the vector in the standard basis and then the matrix would be $K^{-1}DK$.